# Adding subtitles to video with moviepy requiring encoding

Tags: python, moviepy, video-editing, srt, video-subtitles

I have a srt file named `subtitles.srt` that is non-English, and I followed the instructions of the documentation and source code of the moviepy package (https://moviepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/moviepy/video/tools/subtitles.html):

```
from moviepy.video.tools.subtitles import SubtitlesClip
from moviepy.video.io.VideoFileClip import VideoFileClip
generator = lambda txt: TextClip(txt, font='Georgia-Regular', fontsize=24, color='white')
sub = SubtitlesClip("subtitles.srt", generator, encoding='utf-8')
```

And this gives the error `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding'`.

In the source code, the class `SubtitlesClip` does have a keyword argument `encoding`. Does that mean the version of the source code is outdated or something? And what can I do about this? I even attempted to copy the source code for `moviepy.video.tools.subtitles` with the `encoding` keyword argument directly to my code, yet it led to more errors like at the line:

```
from moviepy.decorators import convert_path_to_string
```

it failed to import the decorator `convert_path_to_string`.

The source code does not seem to agree with what I have installed. Anyway to fix it? If not, are there any good alternatives of Python libraries for inserting subtitles or video editing in general?

Edit: My current solution is to create a child class of `SubtitlesClip` and override the constructor of the parent class:

```
from moviepy.video.tools.subtitles import SubtitlesClip
from moviepy.video.VideoClip import TextClip, VideoClip
from moviepy.video.compositing.CompositeVideoClip import CompositeVideoClip
import re



from moviepy.tools import cvsecs

def file_to_subtitles_with_encoding(filename):
    """ Converts a srt file into subtitles.

    The returned list is of the form ``[((ta,tb),'some text'),...]``
    and can be fed to SubtitlesClip.

    Only works for '.srt' format for the moment.
    """
    times_texts = []
    current_times = None
    current_text = ""
    with open(filename,'r',encoding='utf-8') as f:
        for line in f:
            times = re.findall("([0-9]*:[0-9]*:[0-9]*,[0-9]*)", line)
            if times:
                current_times = [cvsecs(t) for t in times]
            elif line.strip() == '':
                times_texts.append((current_times, current_text.strip('\n')))
                current_times, current_text = None, ""
            elif current_times:
                current_text += line
    return times_texts


class SubtitlesClipUTF8(SubtitlesClip):
    def __init__(self, subtitles, make_textclip=None):
        
        VideoClip.__init__(self, has_constant_size=False)

        if isinstance(subtitles, str):
            subtitles = file_to_subtitles_with_encoding(subtitles)

        #subtitles = [(map(cvsecs, tt),txt) for tt, txt in subtitles]
        self.subtitles = subtitles
        self.textclips = dict()

        if make_textclip is None:
            make_textclip = lambda txt: TextClip(txt, font='Georgia-Bold',
                                        fontsize=24, color='white',
                                        stroke_color='black', stroke_width=0.5)

        self.make_textclip = make_textclip
        self.start=0
        self.duration = max([tb for ((ta,tb), txt) in self.subtitles])
        self.end=self.duration
        
        def add_textclip_if_none(t):
            """ Will generate a textclip if it hasn't been generated asked
            to generate it yet. If there is no subtitle to show at t, return
            false. """
            sub =[((ta,tb),txt) for ((ta,tb),txt) in self.textclips.keys()
                   if (ta<=t<tb)]
            if not sub:
                sub = [((ta,tb),txt) for ((ta,tb),txt) in self.subtitles if
                       (ta<=t<tb)]
                if not sub:
                    return False
            sub = sub[0]
            if sub not in self.textclips.keys():
                self.textclips[sub] = self.make_textclip(sub[1])

            return sub

        def make_frame(t):
            sub = add_textclip_if_none(t)
            return (self.textclips[sub].get_frame(t) if sub
                    else np.array([[[0,0,0]]]))

        def make_mask_frame(t):
            sub = add_textclip_if_none(t)
            return (self.textclips[sub].mask.get_frame(t) if sub
                    else np.array([[0]]))
        
        self.make_frame = make_frame
        hasmask = bool(self.make_textclip('T').mask)
        self.mask = VideoClip(make_mask_frame, ismask=True) if hasmask else None
```

I actually only changed two lines, but I have to create a new class and redefine the whole thing, so I doubt whether it's really necessary. Any better solution than this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `latest` version in the documentation (the one you are looking at) corresponds to a dev version 2.x, which is not released to PyPI yet. The version you have installed through pip is most likely 1.0.3, which is the latest on PyPI, and it doesn't allow an `encoding` parameter.

From the [PR](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/pull/1043) where the feature was introduced, you can see that it's only been tagged for release in 2.x versions.

Copying only that file to your source code will most likely not work, because it will depend on changes that happened in between the two versions. However, if you feel adventurous, you can install the *dev* version of the package, by following the **Method by hand** section in moviepy's [docs](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/install.html#installation).